# Return data if relationship doesn't exists between the two nodes Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

There are two Nodes with label

1. Order
2. Status (By default 5 Status Nodes are created)

   - `{code: START}`
   - `{code: PLACED}`
   - `{code: DISPATCHED}`
   - `{code: DELIVERED}`
   - `{code: COMPLETED}`

There exists a relationship between two nodes "**HAS_STATUS**". When the order proceeds I've made a relation of **order** with the respective **status**.

```
        (start)      (placed)
           Status  Status
               \   /
                \ / 
     Status----Order1------Status
(dispatched)     |           (delivered)
                 |
               Status 
             (completed)



        (start)      (placed)
           Status  Status
               \   /
                \ / 
     Status----Order2------Status
(dispatched)               (delivered)
```

I want to execute 2 queries:

1. Get all orders which are completed
2. Get all order which are not completed

For the first one **it returns Order1 as expected**:

> Match (order:Order)-[:HAS_STATUS]-(status:Status) where
> status.code="COMPLETED" return order{.*}

For the second **it returns Order1 and Order2 (It should return only Order2)**

> Match (order:Order)-[:HAS_STATUS]-(status:Status) where not status.code="COMPLETED" return order{.*}

***Please help me on the second one. I hope my explaination made you clear about the scenario.***

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following two queries:

1. query:

   Match (order:Order)
   WHERE (order)-[:HAS_STATUS]-(:Status{code:"COMPLETED"})
   return order{.*}
2. query:

   Match (order:Order)
   WHERE NOT (order)-[:HAS_STATUS]-(:Status{code:"COMPLETED"})
   return order{.*}